# get_terms() retrieving 90K rows, generating performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, query-optimization

Recently I have have received under my responsibility the company's wordpress site, suffers from extreme performance issues...

I have started investigating, installed Query Monitor and discovered several problemas:

**Get_terms()**.

The site's theme use heavily this method in many shortcodes. All this shortcodes call get_terms and at the end, it sums up to 88K queries that slows the site dramatically.

If I'll replace the theme, or disable Polylang, the memory will shrink down from 260mb to 20mb-30mb.

I'm Adding a print of the site's query monitor. (removing the theme's name to protect its identity)

[image: Query monitor print screen]

The slow query is this

```sql
SELECT t.*, tt.* 
  FROM wp_terms AS t
 INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
             ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
 WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_translations')
  AND tt.count > 0 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

I have managed several themes before. Never seen a theme that using so heavily get_terms().

Listen, I'm not a PHP guy. I'm a front man who does themes and enjoy it, but I think that in this case there is some problem of the way the method is called and I cant find out where.

As we can see in the print above, the plugin calls `extend_shortcodes` which calls `get_terms()` inside `taxonomy.php`. I was trying to find the expensive method call, and cannot seem to locate it.

Did anyone encountered a problem like that before? Does anyone has some tips to share? My site gets stuck too many times cause of this problem and I will apreciaste any help I can get.

Comment: "wordpress site" and "suffers from extreme performance issues", Somehow I don't doubt that

Comment: If you have access to run queries on the database, take one of the expensive queries and prefix it with the `EXPLAIN` keyword. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM...` this  will show you if the table is using the appropriate indexes (and if not you can add them) or if full table scans are in effect.

Comment: @SimonK getting right over it! I've always been using phpmyadmin.. Yes I know, lame low level user :) but in this new company, I'm supposed to use command line. All is new here for me :) If its not too much to ask, can you elaborate a little more, or even give a link that uou like, on the subject? For example, what have you meant when said  "table is using the appropriate indexes", or "if I can add them", or even regarding "table scans are in effect". All is new to me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to give an in-depth run down but think about it in this simple way... Lets say you have to look up a physical copy of an encyclopedia for some topic. You know the encyclopedia has information about the topic, you just don't know where. Rather than scanning the full encyclopedia to find the topic (very time consuming), you look at the index (very quick) to see what page that topic is mentioned on and go straight to that page from there. Now apply the same logic to your query.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Thank you @SimonK. If no one answeres me in several days, I'll enter in contact with you, to turn your comment into an answer, for me to accept it.

Comment: Install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/  If you still have trouble, provide more information about the queries that are slow.

Comment: Why grab all 88K rows?  Can't you settle for a much smaller set of rows?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - This forum is littered with "performance issues" with WP, though "extreme" is stretching it a bit.  WP is good for modest-sized datasets, but it does not scale well.  88K rows seems to be an example of scaling beyond WP's capabilities.

Comment: @neoswf - Use the commandline tool "mysql".  In that you can do things like `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Provide those for the 88K query; I can probably recommend _specific_ `INDEXes` to add.

Comment: @RickJames thanks a ton for all the time you provided for my problem. Thanks a lot for all the tips. I'll checkout for sure your plugin.

Comment: "it sums up to 88K queries" -- Is that what is in the image?  Is that 88K separate SQL statements?  Or one SQL statement that delivers 88K rows?  (The latter is likely to be _much_ faster.)

Comment: @RickJames I think its the query appearing in my post. How can I know the answer to your question? Im not an sql genius master, yet. And I also do not have phpmyadmin installed on the google cloud sql. You have written that you can recommend specific indexes. Can you please do that? Also a good idea is to post all your recomendations as a post, for me to upvote it. Thanks a lot!!! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 90K row resultset from that very common WordPress query of yours is, to put it bluntly, ludicrously, insanely, over-the-top, large. That term / taxonomy subsystem is mostly used to organize categories and tags. But, your theme, and possibly your Polylang translation system, uses it somehow to manage various languages.

I did an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on a test site and found that the MySQL (in my case MariaDB 10.6.5) query planner, for a very common value of `wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy`, chooses to ignore the indexes on that table and scan the whole thing.  For a less common value it uses the indexes, which is want we want.  I guess if you run an EXPLAIN as suggested in the comments, you'll get something similar.

I know my remarks above may as well be written in ancient Klingon. So read on.

Indexing your table is not the way to solve your problem. The problem is a bloated `wp_term_taxonomy` table, and / or your theme code to retrieve all that bloat inappropriately. (What can a theme possibly do with a 90K-row result set???)

How to address the problem?

1. install a plugin like Younes JFR's Advanced Database Cleaner. Take a look at the wp_term_taxonomy table. Does it offer you any chances to clean things up?  If so, use it. (Back up your database first, of course.)
2. Ask the Polylang support people for help. You can say "90K `'post_translations'` rows? Really? WTF?" There may be some way in Polylang to clean this up. And, if in fact Polylang uses the term taxonomy system to store translated posts, well, WTF?  Show them your Query Monitor output.
3. Ask the people responsible for your theme why they need all that data to expand their shortcodes. (I assume it's a custom theme.) Show them your Query Monitor output too.

I know this is not a solution to your problem. But it should get you further down the troubleshooting path.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for all the investment in my post. The edits and directions. I'll go after that and return when I'll have something to update. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Jones, I have ran the plugin, and I got some crazy results. First- it have not offered me to clean the desired table. Instead, I have discovered that wp_posts is 224,142 rows & 268.8MB and wp_postmeta is 1,592,531 rows and 352.1MB. Does it make any sense? These are huge numbers. Is it normal for a wp site to have them?

Comment: Yes, that amount of content might make sense. Then again, it might not. Is this a WooCommerce store? Or a widely deployed bulletin board? It's hard to do anything more for you without knowing a lot more about your site. But that kind of advice isn't in the scope of StackOverflow Q&A.

Comment: Neither this nor that @o-jones. It's a site with 500 posts that represents a kind of a  catalog. It's a health related website. There's no WooComerce installed, neither bulletin. The site goes down every 2-3 days, and I'm trying to figure out the reason. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Add this "composite" index:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy ADD INDEX(taxonomy, count);
```

I would use the mysql commandline tool; phpmyadmin or workbench could be used instead.